# Ultravnc - no password set error

Tags: windows-10, vnc, ultravnc

Using UltraVNC 1.2.2.7 as "server" (Win10 1709) on a remote PC and as viewer on my Win 7 PC. Viewer is working fine on 20+ other PCs.

I have set password on the server and rebooted.

When I try to connect to the remote PC it refuses the connection with a message that the password is not set. The rejection reason is probably bogus as I can see the password change in the ini file.

Firewall is set as on other working PCs.

Forum posts are all old, no mention of recent OS or version. Surprised others are not having the issue.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: The UltraVNC version is probably incorrect. The latest is 1.2.1.7.

Comment: Try this, perhaps? https://www.paperstreetonline.com/2015/03/17/ultravnc-password-not-set-how-to-install-as-a-system-service/